# Inner Content blocks (imo) not working 2sxc module DNN

Tags: module, dotnetnuke, 2sxc

According to: https://github.com/2sic/2sxc/issues/1320

In my opinion this is bug. Earlier I used my custom contents and templates with inner content without problem. I did not even have to use @ Edit.ContextAttributes.

Content types:

1. Section content type has field for inner content block. [Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QHqEB.png)

   ```
   @{
   var sectionName = "";
   if(Content.Kotwica != "")
   {
       sectionName = Content.Kotwica;
   }
   else
   {
       sectionName = "sc-entity-" + @Content.EntityID;
   }
   }


   @if((Dnn.User.IsInRole("Administrators") || @Dnn.User.IsSuperUser) && DotNetNuke.Common.Globals.IsEditMode())
   {
       
           @Content.Nazwa
       
       
           @Edit.Toolbar(Content, actions: "edit,layout,remove,moveup,movedown,template-develop", settings: new { show = "always"})
       
   }

       #@(sectionName) {
           @if(Content.Tlo != "")
           {
               background-image: url(@(Content.Tlo));
               if(!Content.PowtarzajTlo)
               {
                   background-size: cover;
               }
               if(Content.Parallax)
               {
                   background-attachment: fixed;
               }
           }
           @if(Content.KolorTla != "")
           {
               background-color: @(Content.KolorTla);
           }
           @if(Content.MarginesWew != "")
           {
               padding: @(Content.MarginesWew);
           }
           @if(Content.MarginesZew != "")
           {
               margin: @(Content.MarginesZew);
           }
       }
       @if(Content.Nakrycie != "") {
           #sc-entity-@(Content.EntityID) .sc-overlay {
               background: @Content.Nakrycie
           }
       }

   @if(Content.Nakrycie != "") {  }
   @if(Content.Wysrodkuj)
   {
       @:
   }

   <div class="editor-styles">@Html.Raw(Content.Tresc)</div>
   <div class="sc-content-block-list" @Edit.ContextAttributes(Content, field: "ModulContent")>
       @foreach(var contentBlock in AsDynamic(Content.ModulContent)){
           @contentBlock.Render()
       }
   </div>


   @if(Content.Wysrodkuj)
   {
       @:
   }
   @if(Content.Parallax)
   {
       
           jQuery(document).ready(function() {
               if(jQuery().parallax) {
                   jQuery('#@(sectionName)').parallax("50%", 0.3);
               }
           });
       
   }
   @if(Content.Animacja != "")
   {
       
           jQuery(document).ready(function() {
               if(jQuery().viewportChecker) {
                   var entity@(Content.EntityID) = jQuery('#@(sectionName)');
                   entity@(Content.EntityID).viewportChecker({
                       classToAdd: 'animated ' + entity@(Content.EntityID).data('animate'),
                       repeat: false,
                       offset: -50
                   });
               }
           });
       
   }
   ```
2. Typical textbox content type has typical textbox field and additonal. [Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Old6.png)

   ```
   @if((Dnn.User.IsInRole("Administrators") || @Dnn.User.IsSuperUser) && DotNetNuke.Common.Globals.IsEditMode())
   {
       
           @Content.Nazwa
       
       
           @Edit.Toolbar(Content, actions: "edit,layout,remove,moveup,movedown,template-develop", settings: new { show = "always"})
       
   }

       @if(Content.NaglowekTekst != "")
       {
           if(Content.NaglowekRodzaj == "foo1") { 

   @Content.NaglowekTekst }
               if(Content.NaglowekRodzaj == "foo2") { 

   @Content.NaglowekTekst }
                   if(Content.NaglowekRodzaj == "foo3") { @Content.NaglowekTekst }
                   if(Content.NaglowekRodzaj == "foo4") { @Content.NaglowekTekst }
                   if(Content.NaglowekRodzaj == "foo5") { @Content.NaglowekTekst }
                   if(Content.NaglowekRodzaj == "foo6") { @Content.NaglowekTekst }
       }
       @Html.Raw(Content.Tresc)

   @if(Content.Animacja != "")
   {
       
           jQuery(document).ready(function() {
               if(jQuery().viewportChecker) {
                   var entity@(Content.EntityID) = jQuery('#sc-entity-@Content.EntityID');
                   entity@(Content.EntityID).viewportChecker({
                       classToAdd: 'animated ' + entity@(Content.EntityID).data('animate'),
                       repeat: false,
                       offset: -50
                   });
               }
           });
       
   }
   ```
3. Video with problem

   https://www.screencast.com/t/Bl0hUXmt

Comment: Note: I think you're right, that it's a bug. we'll look into it soon, but ATM we're fully focused on getting 9.7 out...

Comment: Version 9.5 is okay... probably

Comment: Version 9.10 fixed